# What problem does GHCi/Haskell have with the black pawn unicode character?

Tags: haskell, unicode, chess, ghci

Of the following lines, Haskell seems to have problems only with the last one. The error when I load the file in GHCi is `error: parse error on input ‘♟’`.

```
xK = '♔'
xK = '♕'
xR = '♖'
xB = '♗'
xN = '♘'
xP = '♙'
xk = '♚'
xk = '♛'
xr = '♜'
xb = '♝'
xn = '♞'
xp = '♟︎'
```

Whatever the reason is, I find so strange that everything is just fine with the other 11 characters.

Might be important: I copied the characters straight from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode).

Comment: Could it be that it's composed of two characters, BLACK CHESS PAWN
and VARIATION SELECTOR-15?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your black pawn is secretly two codepoints. Compare:

```
> "♟" -- entered myself
"\9823"
> "♟︎" -- copied and pasted from the question
"\9823\65038"
```

If you include only the first codepoint or change your binding from a `Char` to a `String`, it will work fine.

Comment: So it's black magic affecting the black pawn. It kinda make sense...